# Wiring timer switch with only two wires in the box

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am attempting to wire a Honeywell in wall timer switch to where an existing single pole switch is. The timer has 3 wires black, white(neutral) and blue(load) and the wall only has two black wires and a ground. Is there a way to do this correctly? I connected the white and black timer switch wires to the two blacks and capped off the blue but the timer is powering on and off and not staying on. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Did the product not come with any literature? You're describing a switch loop, so you probably don't have a neutral at the box.

Comment: They do make timer switches that don't require a neutral.  Sounds like that's what you need.

Comment: @isherwood, I feel like we need some canonical question we can link to for "I'm trying to do something that requires a neutral but I don't have one" questions.

Comment: We need quite a few canonical questions. But no easy way to make them discoverable.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact tons of up votes makes them float to the top _if_ the OP searches, correct?

Comment: @FreeMan If they happen to hit on the right keywords. What would work better though is a Canonical (or some other term) section on the page, which would include things like this item and a handful of others, such as "how to wire receptacles", "general panel/breaker how-to", etc. People who don't know the terms (because they are new to this stuff) don't know what to search for. But if there is an obvious place for common problems then they'll look at that.

Comment: Does Codidact have that? ;) _I need to stop by there, it's been a while_

Comment: Most timers are mechanical rundown timers and don't require neutral. Why use one that does?  Oh, because you want the push buttons. Well, that has a cost: now you need to get power to the timer.

Answer (score 0):

Any switch that is more than a simple mechanical switch:

- Timer
- Dimmer
- Smart Switch (e.g., WiFi, programmable, remote control, etc.)
- Motion Detector

needs to get some power for its own guts, in addition to power for the lights (or other devices) that it controls. (Actually, basic dimmers don't *necessarily* need power, but more advanced models often do.)

There are 3 main ways to get power:

- Neutral - This is the most straightforward. And, in fact, newer code requires neutral in most switch boxes (unless wired using conduit) for exactly this reason. But that is a relatively new code requirement and many older houses (like mine) have *switch loops* with no neutral in the box.
- Battery - The problem is that batteries require changing. Either frequently (expensive) or infrequently (Why isn't this working after 2 years of working just fine? Must be time to replace it. *No, just needs a new battery.*) Some manufacturers actually have switches where the main switch requires neutral but a secondary switch (e.g., for a 3-way or 4-way setup) is really just a battery-powered remote that *looks like* a regular switch.
- Ground - This is only allowed when specifically designed to use ground. There are limits to the amount of power for safety reasons and to avoid problems with GFCI and AFCI circuits.

The end result is that if you have a switch loop then you either need to find a way to add a neutral or find a different device that doesn't require neutral. Adding a neutral is easy with conduit - literally run an additional wire (white or gray) through the conduit. But with cables you can't do that - you have to replace the entire cable. Replacing a cable is easy in an unfinished area, but not so easy in the rest of the house.